# How to locate undetectable errors in BlueJ when the compiler doesn't provide a location?

Tags: compiler-errors, bluej

So I just wrote a small program for school and I came across this issue:
BlueJ tells me
"Error(s) found in class"
but not where they are, they are just not underlined or marked in any way, so I cannot see what kind of error it is either.
It's really weird because I have actually had this in the past and at some point, the problem was just simply gone but this one really won't disappear. I think my code is all correct, I have checked it a bunch of times. So I here I am wondering about this general issue.
I'm blaming BlueJ for this one.

Well I checked my code a dozen times and still can't seem to find this *undetectable* error. So I was just wondering what I can do in order for BlueJ to tell me where it is, perhaps.
No other searches so far have helped me really.

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.